# Textbox throwing an error when empty

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I just try to make

```
 if (txtNo.Text != "" || txtName.Text != "" || txtAddress.Text != "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Fill Textbox");
            }
```

[image]

I just click update with not value in textbox.

I just make clear when the textbox in the user press the update button, then the warning messages are displayed so that the user recharges. Without being subject to error or out of the program, I am using SQL SERVER to save data.

Comment: you are not validating the controls in btnUpdate_Click before trying to update the table.

Comment: Look at the error message - it is saying Connection Property is not being initialized. Set up you connection properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your button code like this.

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtNo.Text == "" || txtName.Text == "" || txtAddress.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Fill TextBox");
                return;
            }
            SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand(UPDATE...
            Connection.Buka.....();
            CMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show(....)
            Connection.Tutu.....();
        }
```

Comment: thank you very helpful answer ,,,, you understand what I mean ....
Thank you very much..

this is answer..... #keepy

Answer (score 2):

Your error states that your SQL Connection is not set up properly. Wrap your SQL command in a using statement with a SQL connection. You will need to supply a valid connection string to your database.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
     SqlCommand cmd ...
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() ...
}
```

Comment: It is not my intention?

Answer (score 2):

Error is not related to `textbox.text` value.It is related to `sqlcommand`.

Please note that whenever you are using `sqlcommand`. you  have to declare new `sqlconnection` object with connection string. And then apply it to `sqlcommand`.

Please check below query for example

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not the string, which I would recommend you to use `String.IsNullOrEmpty("YOURSTRING")` 

You have a problem with you database connection. Set this up properly, creating an instance of SQLConnection and try again.

Comment: I'm not questioning why the error appears ,,,
I asked I just make clear when the textbox in the user press the update button, then the warning messages are displayed so that the user recharges. Without being subject to error or out of the program, I am using SQL SERVER to save data.

I am sorry if you are not familiar with my writing ,, I am so grateful that you are taking your time to answer ..
i\

Answer (score -1):

**comparing strings with the `.Equals()` method** instead of the `==` operator is best practice, may not solve your problem but the code will be cleaner

Answer (score -1):

```
if((!string.isnullorwhitespace(txtNo.Text)) || (!string.isnullorwhitespace(txtName.Text)) ||(!string.isnullorwhitespace(txtAddress.Text)))
{

    enter code here

}
```

Comment: Would this solve the problem with his db connection?

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are discouraged on SO.

Comment: is too long.... but thank for your time...